# How to show my .deb package in a particular section

Tags: deb, ubuntu

i had made my own .deb package for media player developed by me,but when i install it in my

kubuntu 10.04 it install successfully but not shows under a particular section like

"Multimedia" so please tell me how to show my deb package into a particular section because i

am going to release it over internet so the users from whole world can download it and use

it.

From example my VLC media player after installation shows under Multimedia Section.

-Thanks

Comment: You mean that it should be visible under the "Applications" menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the DP (Debian Policy) you need a file "menu" under debian/

http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/ch-dother.en.html#s-menu

and  the menu policy:

http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/menu-policy/ch2.html